# What is the Best way to run an airdrop on EOS?

Tags: cleos

How can I issue my tokens and distribute them to the Genesis accounts? Any help will be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 1):

There are a load of considerations first off and it may be good to take legal advice. However, once you have decided to do your airdrop then technically it is not very tricky.

First buy some RAM and stake a couple of thousand EOS on CPU and a little on net.

You'll need a token contract which you can deploy (you can reuse the eosio.token code). Then deploy it and issue the tokens to a main account for airdropping purposes.

The genesis snapshot is available in a load of places - all you need to do is run transfers to all the accounts. Bash script cleos commands or eosjs best for this.

For eosDAC we had a very specific other distribution so we dropped our tokens in a frozen (no transfers allowed) state for validation. This is handy if you want to make sure you don't missed anyone out. eosDAC has a powerful drop/verification script here - https://github.com/eosdac/DACtools/tree/master/drop%20tool which can be configured for quite rapid airdrops.

Answer (score 0):

See the following links.
Tools and examples for air drop are provided.

https://github.com/EOSEssentials/EOSDrops
https://github.com/grogn/airdropExamples/tree/master/EOS/contracts